# Lists and number validation

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
strnumsold = str()
numsold = int()
Flag = False
index = 0
totprice = 0.0
avgsold = 0.0
aboveavg = 0
belowavg = 0
strnumcheck = str()
numcheck = float()


print("Welcome to the Home Sales Calculator!")
print(" _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _")
strnumsold = input("\nHow many homes were sold in the past year? ")
while Flag == False:
    if strnumsold.isdigit():
        numsold = int(strnumsold)
        Flag = True
    else:
        strnumsold = input("That is not a valid number! Try Again!")
Flag = False
tothomes = []
print("\nWhat did the home sell for? (#'s Only) ")
print("**********************************************")
for index in range(numsold):
        tothomes.append(input("{}) $ ".format(index + 1)))
        strnumcheck = tothomes[index]
        if strnumcheck.isdigit():
            numcheck = float(strnumcheck)
            Flag = True
            tothomes[index] = numcheck
        else:
            tothomes[index] = input("That is not a valid number! Try Again! ")
        index = index + 1
        Flag = False
tothomes.sort()
print("**********************************************")
for homes in reversed(tothomes):
    print("   $", "%.2f"%homes)
avgsold = sum(tothomes) / numsold
print("\nThe Average Price of homes sold was: $", "%.2f"%avgsold)
print("The Highest home sold was: ", "%.2f"%max(tothomes))
print("The Lowest home sold was:  ", "%.2f"%min(tothomes))
aboveavg = [above for above in tothomes if above >avgsold]
belowavg = [below for below in tothomes if below <avgsold]
print("The number of homes sold ABOVE Average was: ", len(aboveavg))
print("The number of homes sold BELOW Average was: ", len(belowavg))
```

This is my first program with both lists and number validation.

I have posted how far I am above, and have rewritten this multiple times/ways trying to get it right.

My number validation works, but when entered again after the cue "try again",
it won't fully run through the loop and change the string into a float.

It works as it suppose to when the numbers are entered correctly.
Here is a sample of what's happening when an incorrect input is given:

Welcome to the Home Sales Calculator!

---

```
How many homes were sold in the past year? 3

What did the home sell for? (#'s Only) 
**********************************************
1) $ 25
2) $ 36
3) $ m
That is not a valid number! Try Again! 24
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\troythomas448\Desktop\ITCS1140\Assignments\Thomas, Troy Lab#8.3.py", line 37, in <module>
    tothomes.sort()
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the question? if you have problems getting that to work you must be more specific

Comment: Please also note that Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a tutorial or code-writing service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how the different facets of the site work in general.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to get my number validation to properly work, thus rejecting the string, and allowing the user to "try again".

Comment: When the user enters in non number characters, it will ask the user to "try again". When properly entered, it does not change it to a float, so the program errors.

Comment: @Troy, you can probably improve the post by making it shorter and focused to the part of the code where you have difficulties (it is far too long in its current form).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us sample input, expected output, the *actual* output, and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks you're getting.

Comment: Sorry for the first post everyone, this is my first question on here. It has been updated, hopefully to you satisfactions.  Need any more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Holy cow!
Got it to run, and it was the smallest thing in the world!

In my For Loop, I added an additional While Loop over my If statement.

It still wouldn't run, and I realized in my Else for my If statement, I had to switch tothomes[index] to strnumcheck.

I showed what I changed down below:

```
print("\nWhat did the home sell for? (#'s Only) ")
print("**********************************************")
for index in range(numsold):
    tothomes.append(input("{}) $ ".format(index + 1)))
    strnumcheck = tothomes[index]
    while Flag == False:                          <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<!
        if strnumcheck.isdigit():
            numcheck = float(strnumcheck)
            Flag = True
            tothomes[index] = numcheck
        else:
            strnumcheck = input                   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<!
("That is not a valid number! Try Again! ")
    index = index + 1
    Flag = False
```